# HTML Background Missing After Site Migration

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, ubuntu-18.04

I made a powerpoint presentation & converted it to HTML at https://www.idrsolutions.com/online-powerpoint-to-html5-converter
The output html page on the mentioned site looks perfect for me.
But after I downloaded zip and put the contents on my new site (Ubuntu & PHP7 fresh install) I don't see the blue background.
My site is https://castaneda.su/DK/221023
I tried to make these steps for my another site https://alpin52.ru/221023 (preconfigured by host provider) and the look is as required.
I think the problem is that I missed installing some component on the server. But I cannot figure out which. Thanks.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I made modifications to each html page file as suggested by Chris. This workaround is acceptable since the count of pages isn't large.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's because you are missing HTTPS in the new domain so the browser is skipping some resources it considers insecure to load over non-HTTPS. Fix your HTTPS certificate situation and this problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

I used the inspect element to see the source code and saw that the div with the id (pg1Overlay) had the style

```css
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
-webkit-user-select: none;
```

So, I changed it to

```css
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
background-color: blue;
-webkit-user-select: none;
```

and then the page was blue.